# Why the CJKglue setting doesn't work in the document class of ctexart?

Tags: xecjk, ctex

First an MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\xeCJKsetup{CJKglue={\hskip 10pt plus 0.08\baselineskip}}
%default value: \hskip 0pt plus 0.08\baselineskip

\begin{document}
话说天下大势，分久必合，合久必分。周末七国分争，并入于秦。及秦灭之后，楚、汉分争，又并入于汉。汉朝自高祖斩白蛇而起义，一统天下，后来光武中兴，传至献帝，遂分为三国。推其致乱之由，殆始于桓、灵二帝。桓帝禁锢善类，崇信宦官。及桓帝崩，灵帝即位，大将军窦武、太傅陈蕃，共相辅佐。时有宦官曹节等弄权，窦武、陈蕃谋诛之，机事不密，反为所害，中涓自此愈横。
\end{document}
```

After compiling the codes in `XeLaTeX`, you will find that `CJKglue` setting doesn't work in the document class of `ctexart`. Then how to make it work in the document class of `ctexart`? Note that I hope all the spaces between Chinese characters in all the sizes be set as above.

Comment: Unfortunately `ctex` "takes over" `xeCJK`'s `CJKglue` setting and this behavior is documented very vaguely. See explanation from `ctex-kit` maintainer @qinglee and two alternatives (posted by myself) in https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/450. Option 1: setting `\ctexset{linestretch=\maxdimen}` to give control back to `xeCJK`. Option 2: setting `\ziju{<ratio of a CJK normal width>}`.

Answer (score 2):

The class sets the default at begin document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ctexart}


%default value: \hskip 0pt plus 0.08\baselineskip

\begin{document}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKglue={\hskip 20pt plus 0.08\baselineskip}}

话说天下大势，分久必合，合久必分。周末七国分争，并入于秦。及秦灭之后，楚、汉分争，又并入于汉。汉朝自高祖斩白蛇而起义，一统天下，后来光武中兴，传至献帝，遂分为三国。推其致乱之由，殆始于桓、灵二帝。桓帝禁锢善类，崇信宦官。及桓帝崩，灵帝即位，大将军窦武、太傅陈蕃，共相辅佐。时有宦官曹节等弄权，窦武、陈蕃谋诛之，机事不密，反为所害，中涓自此愈横。
\end{document}
```

Comment: @M.Logic it may be documented, I find `texdoc ctexart` a little challenging to read:-)

Comment: But it brings about another problem: it won't change the spaces between Chinese characters in footnotes. Aha, by the way, it's indeed hard to learn and read Chinese ...

Comment: @M.Logic it presumably resets this on every font size change (oh it's probably the \normalsize in `\begin{document}` that caused the first issue)